# How to reset the QValidator to accept all input once some Validator is used

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qvalidator

I have used the `setValidator(QIntValidator)` in PyQt. How to reset this Validator to accept all the inputs like it was before ? I want to dynamically handle the validation thats why ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to [Qt documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#setValidator):

> If `v == 0`, `setValidator()` removes the current input validator

So, use `setValidator(None)`.